# Postgres unnest multidimensional array to columns?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

Based on previous posts, I can unnest a multidimensional array to an integer[], however I would like to be able to create multiple columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_2d_1d(ANYARRAY, OUT a ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS SETOF ANYARRAY AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOREACH a SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Then if I execute:

`select unnest_2d_1d(array[[1,2],[4,5]]);`

Result:

### *column*

12

45

However what I am trying to achieve is:

### *column1 | column2*

1       |     2

4       |     5

I also tried to unnest the result but it didnt work as it only creates a unique column with all the information

Comment: If you want to return several columns then return several columns instead of single array column. To split result into columns just split it like `select a[1] as col1, a[2] as col2 from unnest_2d_1d(array[[1,2],[4,5]]) as a;`

Comment: Oo' ..I didnt realize it was so trivial, thanks a lot!

Comment: I reread my answer and it looks like "If you want to do something then just do it!" :) Sorry, hope it was helpful :) Good luck!